# Change value, based on current month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following tables

Here is the table I have (Picture 1). Similar tables would be generated for each month, but each month might have more or less rows compared to the previous. It all depends on the data that needs to be inserted. What is important is the cell named "TOTAL" for each month.

So, on a different sheet I have the Picture 2 table, where I need to populate the TOTAL of the month we are currently in. In this case I would need to have the November Total populated.

Picture 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U3bX.png
Picture 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHimY.png

How can I populate the values for "Total for the current month" automatically, based on the current month? Meaning that when the month changes, the value for that cell should change as well and should be populated from the current month's "TOTAL" cell.

Thank you all!

Comment: So what happens next month? Are you keeping October there, and if so, what does that value look like? Still a 1?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're trying to pull, but does this help? `=TEXT(EDATE(TODAY(),1),"MMMM")` & `=TEXT(EDATE(TODAY(),2),"MMMM")`

Comment: The month name, changes automatically with the following formula - TEXT(TODAY(),"MMMM"). The second sheet is purely for having easy access to the total for the current month, but on a separate sheet. BUT if you are referring to the main table, there would be similar tables for each month, just generated lower in the sheet.

Comment: P.b can you share a bit more details? Should i put this formula in the second table directly?

Comment: The formulas will result in current month + 1 & 2 respectively. I thought that may have been useful for the example you gave before the edit.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT due to the refined question:

You need to use SUMIFS to sum the TOTAL where the related date matches the current month.

Assuming that your criteria is that you always calculate the month based on TODAY(), we can use TODAY() as well in the formula.

So if you have your Value cell in B2, paste this in:

```
=SUMIFS(I:I;H:H;">="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY());MONTH(TODAY());1);H:H;"<="&EOMONTH(TODAY();0))
```

where I:I is the TOTAL column and H:H is the dates column in your orders table.

The >= and <= indicates the range of dats between the first and last day of the CURRENT month (based on TODAY()).

Comment: @MartinPetrov please mark as solved if this solves your problem :)

Comment: Thanks! I use VLOOKUP on a daily basis, but in my case it would not be very efficient. I guess the simple example I gave in my question was not very correct. I have updated my question now.

Comment: Sorry for misleading you initially :)

Comment: @MartinPetrov I edited the answer to address the modified question, check it out :)